# Without using module, how can I determine the width of an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In other words, if I am presented with the number 54352, I want an expression that will tell me the width of that number is 5. I could use a for each loop to do this I know, but that seems rather cumbersome. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `len(str(54352))` which will return 5 by converting it into a string, and returning the length of the string representation of the number.

Another way, a bit longer, would be:

```
def ilen(n):
    i=0
    while n != 0:
      n /= 10
      i += 1
    return i

ilen(54352)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually is more like `len(str(abs(n)))` because `-1` should probably have length 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
n = 54352
print (len(str(abs(n))))
```

Amended as user2722968 is correct.